# Null value in Model Class property in MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a question. I need to save all values of my model.
Class

```
public class AssessmentAreaContent
{
  //SysAssessmentSubAreaCategory is enity model class
  public List<SysAssessmentSubAreaCategory> ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory;   
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult AssessmentArea(int id)
            { 
              var model = new AssessmentAreaContent();
                model.ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory = db.SysAssessmentSubAreaCategory.Where(c => c.AssessmentAreaId == id).ToList();
                return View(model);
            }
```

Controller Http Post Method

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AssessmentArea(Web.Models.AssessmentAreaContent assessmentAreaContent)
        {

            //assessmentAreaContent.ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory is null here ?? ; 
            return RedirectToAction("AssessmentArea", "AssessmentArea");
        }
```

View

```
@model Web.Models.AssessmentAreaContent

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Area";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @{ 

    if (Model != null)
                        {
       foreach (var category in Model.ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory)
                            {           


              <strong>@Html.EditorFor(item => category.AreaCategoryName)</strong>  
                <br />
       }
}
}
<input type="submit" name="button" class="btn" value="Save" />
}
```

I m getting Null value in `assessmentAreaContent.ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory;` 
Im using Entity Framework with MVC 3
How can I do that please ?

Thanks

Comment: Monu ur model is a plain object not an enumeration how do u manage to iterate over it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make an editor template with the name `SysAssessmentSubAreaCategory`. note that name of template is same as type of your list objects. in this template write something like

```
@model Web.Models.SysAssessmentSubAreaCategory
<strong>@Html.EditorFor(item => category.AreaCategoryName)</strong>  
                <br />
```

in your main view just make these changes

```
if (Model != null)
                        {
       Html.EditorFor(x=>x.ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory)
       }
```

leave the rest unchanged. fill out the form and post it and you will have values in the controller.

Comment: Monu u r welcome. analyze the generated html and read this article http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx and you would know why this time list bound automatically

Answer (score 0):

There is no input holding values for `ListSysAssessmentSubAreaCategory` so that in post back you have that property filled.

You need that values  to be saved server side (e.g. in session  ) or be represented in input form.